# Vue compile and render specific component from text JS script

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need compile custom vue js script and render it on page

Example:

```js
let js = `"Hello, please choose your variant:<br /> <pool :id='144'>"`
const component = Vue.compile(js)
```

After (for example):

```js
<div class="user-post">
<component :is="component" />
</div>
```

How i can implement this with vue?

Answer (score 1):

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

You need several things here:

1. Compile your HTML to a component with `compile()`. Note that for that you need a different Vue build in vite.config.js (see below).
2. To make your components available in the new component, assign `components` property to, so the Vue would know components used in the original HTML.
3. If you need some variables used as props use `v-bind`.

```
<script setup>
import Pool from './Pool.vue';
import {compile, ref} from 'vue';

const id = ref('144');

const component = Object.assign(
  compile(`"Hello, please choose your variant:<br /> <pool :id='id'/>"`), {
    components: { Pool }
  });

</script>

<template>
  <component v-bind="{id}"/>
  <br/>
  <input v-model="id">
</template>
```

vite.config.js

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```js
const component = defineComponent({
  components: {Pool},
  template: '<div>Hello, please choose your variant:<br /> <pool :id='144'></div>'
})
```

After

```js
<div class="user-post">
<component :is="component" />
</div>
```